# install driver via CLI without "DefaultSection"

Tags: command-line, installation, windows-installer, driver

I tried to install via CLI driver (FtdiPort)
use microsoft example:
`rundll32.exe setuopapi.dll,installhinfSection ?? 132 .\ftdiport.inf`
I put ?? where in the examples were wrote `defaulSection` but this inf file doesn’t have default section, and i don’t know what to write instead of.
I tried "inf file name-nt... as microsoft suggest:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547344(v=vs.85).aspx  , but every time I got error message box of "installation failed"
how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1) to debug driver installation you need to look to setupapi log file SetupAPI.dev.log (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550900(v=vs.85).aspx)

2) As i see this is PnP driver and can`t be installed with DefaultSection:

"Use DefaultInstall sections only for the installation of class filter drivers, class co-installers, file system filters, and kernel driver services that are not associated with a device node"

Instead you can use devcon/DPInstall (from WDK) or create your own preinstaller with SetupCopyOEMInf function.